# Flutter: Change the parameter passed to a "StatefulWidget"

Tags: parameters, dart, flutter, statefulwidget

I have a `StatefulWidget` named `BounceContainer`. This class contains a parameter `child` like a typical Flutter widget. Basically, it bounces the `child` whenever the user taps on it. The way I pass the **child** parameter as of now is as follow:

```dart
class BounceContainer extends StatefulWidget {
    final Widget child;                 // Declaring "child"
    BounceContainer({this.child});      // Initializing "child"

    // Passing "child" to State

    @override
    _BounceContainerState createState() => _BounceContainerState(this.child);
}

class _BounceContainerState extends State<BounceContainer> {
    Widget child;
    _BounceContainerState(this.child);  // Receiving "child"

    @override 
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The problem, in this case, is that even if the `child` parameter changes, the *child* itself does not update.

For example, if I have a button whose color changes from grey to any random color based on `AnimationController` and I pass this button as `child` parameter to `BounceContainer` class, the button still remains grey and calling `setState()` 
(either from the main program or `BounceContainer` class) also does not force update the *child* widget.

What's the proper way (and also efficient way) to work around this problem?

Comment: You don't need to pass all your parameters to State class. You can access with `widget.child`.

Comment: @siega Thanks that worked for me! ✌

Comment: @siega is it good practice? im using it so often but don't know side effects of that

Comment: I think the greatest advantage here is to reduce code. Otherwise, if you have 10 parameters, you need to create 10 properties in the State and pass all this values down via constructor. @dubace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass all your parameters to State class. You can access them with `widget.child`